# getAuthToken doesn't work in chrome app

Tags: google-chrome-extension, android-pay, google-chrome-app

In my packaged app I call

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({'interactive': true }, function (token) {
    console.log('user token: ' + token);
});
```

but every time i enter with different google accounts it produces the same token. What could possibly go wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean by "enter with different google accounts"? How are you switching Google accounts?

Comment: @abraham, very simple: in chrome web store(or in gmail) push sign out button. Then sign in using another email address.

Comment: As I understand it, the chrome identity is controlled by the Google account signed into the Chrome browser, not the web session for Google.

Comment: @abraham, it's not true. I have bought under one of my google accounts an app and if I change account the web store shows me that I have to buy it again. So web store detects changing of (gmail) accounts. The question is How to make identity react on it? btw, how can I sign out from chrome?

Comment: The Web Store and Chrome are not the same thing. Abraham is correct.

Comment: What you are talking about in the CWS is just the ability to install the app, not what account is actually signed into the app. [Help doc for signing in/out of Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/185277?hl=en&ref_topic=1693469), but I recommend you [create a new Chrome profile instead](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en&ref_topic=1678460).

Comment: @abraham, you have made my day!! thanx man! post your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome app identities are tied to the Google account signed into Chrome. You can [change the current signed in account in Chrome settings](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/185277?hl=en&ref_topic=1693469), but I recommend you [create a new Chrome profile instead](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en&ref_topic=1678460).